# Ruby: de-escape special symbols in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping

I want to do:

```
text.gsub('\a', "\a").gsub('\b', "\b")......gsub('\n', "\n").....gsub('\t', "\t")......gsub('\z', "\z")
```

I came to this code:

```
('a'..'z').each { |sym| text.gsub!("\\#{sym}", "\#{sym}") }
```

but the problem is that I can't generate `"\#{sym}"` here as if it were `"\n"` or `"\t"`.

Comment: what really you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @maximus: I am going to replace \ with \\ but at first I have to replace sequences like \n because they shouldn't be involved. Concerning Regexes - they are too complicated to me.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that he's trying to turn the escaped form of a string ("\n" into a newline, "\t" into a tabstop, etc.).

Comment: @Chuck: yes, you are right. I couldn't imagine that this is hard to understand and so went to deeper explanation for maximus :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There unfortunately isn't a "good" way to do this. The normal case for needing this is decoding a transport format like AJAX, but those libraries just implement the correct mapping themselves, so you rarely need it in your own code. You have two options, really:

1. Write out the mapping yourself, as you did in your original code. One thing you could do to make it more readable would be to create a dictionary and loop over that rather than chaining gsubs.
2. Use `eval` to create a string. For example:

   ```
   c = 'n'
   newline = eval "\"\\#{c}\""
   ```

Comment: I like the `eval` way, but I should skip the \u sequence because it is used to write Unicode symbols and needs to be followed by a code.